# Magento SOAP API error

Tags: php, magento, soap

Sorry for bad English.
Hi i am working in SOAP API in magento. But i am getting exception when i am sending data through SOAP. I have **two** magentos. **magento1** and **magento2**. Its working fine when i send this array directly from **magento1** to SOAP i am not having any issue but in my scenario i have to send this data from **magento1** to **magento2** through CURL. Than in magento2 after some processing i am sending this data to third party using soap. But i am getting exception i am sending same array using same code but in **magento2** i am getting this error.

```
[Message] => The string '1473935705' is not a valid AllXsd value.
```

This is the valid value '1473935705' i am using time() function to get this.
here is array that i am sending through SOAP

```
    Array
(
    [Shipments] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Shipper] => Array
                        (
                            [Reference1] => 100000076
                            [Reference2] => 
                            [AccountNumber] => 5185
                            [PartyAddress] => Array
                                (
                                    [Line1] => Area 223, Block 12
                                    [Line2] => 
                                    [Line3] => 
                                    [City] => Manama
                                    [StateOrProvinceCode] => Manama
                                    [PostCode] => 00973
                                    [CountryCode] => BH
                                )

                            [Contact] => Array
                                (
                                    [Department] => 
                                    [PersonName] => Ahmed Nagi
                                    [Title] => 
                                    [CompanyName] => Ahmed Nagi
                                    [PhoneNumber1] => 33161479
                                    [PhoneNumber1Ext] => 
                                    [PhoneNumber2] => 
                                    [PhoneNumber2Ext] => 
                                    [FaxNumber] => 
                                    [CellPhone] => 33161479
                                    [EmailAddress] => a.nagi@iWorldConnect.bh
                                    [Type] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [Consignee] => Array
                        (
                            [Reference1] => 100000076
                            [Reference2] => 
                            [AccountNumber] => 5185
                            [PartyAddress] => Array
                                (
                                    [Line1] => Road: 123, Block:801
                                    [Line2] => 
                                    [Line3] => 
                                    [City] => Manama
                                    [StateOrProvinceCode] => Manama
                                    [PostCode] => 00973
                                    [CountryCode] => BH
                                )

                            [Contact] => Array
                                (
                                    [Department] => 
                                    [PersonName] => Samsung Inc
                                    [Title] => 
                                    [CompanyName] => Samsung Inc
                                    [PhoneNumber1] => 1122334
                                    [PhoneNumber1Ext] => 
                                    [PhoneNumber2] => 
                                    [PhoneNumber2Ext] => 
                                    [FaxNumber] => 
                                    [CellPhone] => 1122334
                                    [EmailAddress] => samsung@esoq.com
                                    [Type] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [Reference1] => 100000076
                    [Reference2] => 
                    [Reference3] => 
                    [ForeignHAWB] => 
                    [TransportType] => 0
                    [ShippingDateTime] => 1473935705
                    [DueDate] => 1474540505
                    [PickupLocation] => Reception
                    [PickupGUID] => 
                    [Comments] => 
                    [AccountingInstrcutions] => 
                    [OperationsInstructions] => 
                    [Details] => Array
                        (
                            [Dimensions] => Array
                                (
                                    [Length] => 0
                                    [Width] => 0
                                    [Height] => 0
                                    [Unit] => cm
                                )

                            [ActualWeight] => Array
                                (
                                    [Value] => 0.6
                                    [Unit] => KG
                                )

                            [ProductGroup] => DOM
                            [ProductType] => BLK
                            [PaymentType] => P
                            [PaymentOptions] => 
                            [Services] => 
                            [NumberOfPieces] => 2
                            [DescriptionOfGoods] => iPhone 6S 128GB Gold - 1.0000, iPad Air 2 Wi-Fi Cell 64GB Gold - 1.0000
                            [GoodsOriginCountry] => BH
                            [Items] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [PackageType] => Box
                                            [Quantity] => 1
                                            [Weight] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [Value] => 0.100
                                                    [Unit] => Kg
                                                )

                                            [Comments] => iPhone 6S 128GB Gold
                                            [Reference] => 
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [PackageType] => Box
                                            [Quantity] => 1
                                            [Weight] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [Value] => 0.500
                                                    [Unit] => Kg
                                                )

                                            [Comments] => iPad Air 2 Wi-Fi Cell 64GB Gold
                                            [Reference] => 
                                        )

                                )

                            [CashOnDeliveryAmount] => Array
                                (
                                    [Value] => 
                                    [CurrencyCode] => BHD
                                )

                            [CustomsValueAmount] => Array
                                (
                                    [Value] => 
                                    [CurrencyCode] => BHD
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [ClientInfo] => Array
        (
            [AccountCountryCode] => BH
            [AccountEntity] => BAH
            [AccountNumber] => 5185
            [AccountPin] => 432432
            [UserName] => testingapi@aramex.com
            [Password] => R123456789$r
            [Version] => v1.0
            [Source] => 31
        )

    [LabelInfo] => Array
        (
            [ReportID] => 9729
            [ReportType] => URL
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue i was using **time()**. But when i use 
**date("c", time());** its working fine.
Use the argument ‘c’ within the date function which will return a ISO 8601 date, which is whats expected by the web service.